# focus() doesn't work in input (all browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there is tons of questions like that on stackoverflow but none of them solved my problem. I'm  trying to build a small "pyramid" word game. You have to find the right translation for a korean word, then a new input with a new word will pop up. Solve this word, the next input field will pop up, ...

HTML:

```
<input id="ha_1" class="halter" placeholder="안녕하세요"  type="text" onblur="checkSol(id);"></input><br/>
<input id="ha_2" class="halter" placeholder="얼굴" type="text" onblur="checkSol(id);"></input><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_3" class="halter" placeholder="문" type="text" onblur="checkSol(id);"></input><br/><br/>
```

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
// compare if user input is correct solution
if (user_input == solution){
// if correct, display the next input field:
             $('#' + e_dies).nextAll('.halter:first').css('display', 'block');
    // ==> supposed to focus the fadedIn input
             $('#next_input').focus();
// count up to the next word
             l_count++;
// give correct/incorrect feedback
                    if(l_count == last_sol){
                            tell_me.innerHTML = 'Correct';
                        return false;
                    };
            } else if(document.getElementById(e_dies).value == "") {
            tell_me.innerHTML = '';
        }
```

This line here `$('#' + e_dies).nextAll('.halter:first').css('display', 'block');` displays a input field. Right after, `$('#next_input').focus();` is supposed to focus this input field , which just faded in. I tried some solutions like using `setTimeout` or moving it to the end of the function. Nothing worked for me.

Strangely, other commands like  `$('#next_input').css('color', 'red');` work just fine, just the `.focus()` makes trouble.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please check browser compatibility http://caniuse.com/#search=focus

Comment: there seems to be no mention of the JS `focus()` method. I'm using the newest versions of firefox, chrome and edge. in other examples, `.focus()` worked for me, so it has to be a problem within my code I guess. not sure why other changes to the element work (like color change) but not the focus

Comment: What does this solution statnds for

Comment: Where's your element with `next_input` id?

Comment: You don't need a closing input tag `</input>`, if possible provide complete html for your code, it's hard to give answer based on assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question seems to be not that clear i have implemented a small fiddle showing input box focus working on conditional value.I hope this can give some help

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function checkSol(id){
 var solution="testname";
  console.log(event);
  var user_input=event.target.value;
  if (user_input == solution){
// if correct, display the next input field:
            
    // ==> supposed to focus the fadedIn input
             $('#focusinputbox').focus();

  }
}
</script>

<input id="ha_1" class="halter" placeholder="안녕하세요"  type="text" onblur="checkSol(id);" /><br/>
<input id="ha_2" class="halter" placeholder="얼굴" type="text" onblur="checkSol(id);" /><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_3" class="halter" placeholder="문" type="text" onblur="checkSol(id);" /><br/><br/>
<input id ='focusinputbox' placeholder='inputtobefocussed'/>
```

Comment: your script **killed** my browser's *tab*